# Svelte: Disable ESLint Rule

Tags: eslint, svelte

I'm working on a Svelt project that uses ESlint, and I'm trying to disable a rule within my svelte template but can't find any information on how to do so. My code is the following:

```
<script lang="ts">
  const unsubscribe = promiseWritable.subscribe((value) => {
    promise = value;
  });

  onDestroy(unsubscribe);
</script>

{#if !!promise} <---- ESLint error here!
  {#await promise then promiseResult}
    <Info {promiseResult} />
  {/await}
{/if}
```

This results in `{#if !!promise}` having the ESLint error:

`Expected non-Promise value in a boolean conditional.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)`

Regardless of whether I should disable this rule, I'm wondering how I would disable it within the file since adding either:
`// eslint-disable-next-line...` or `<!-- eslint-disable-next-line... -->`
above the line won't disable the error.

For Reference I am using https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3

Answer (score 6):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/3351), you can now add a "magic comment" to your Svelte file to disable individual validations using the form `<!-- svelte-ignore rule-name -->`.

```
<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-mouse-events-have-key-events -->
<div on:mouseover={mouseOver} on:mouseleave={mouseLeave} class="wrapper">
  <slot name="content" />
</div>
```

Comment: This disables svelte's validation, not eslint's.

Answer (score 3):

The `eslint-plugin-svelte` plugin works fine with `<!-- eslint-disable -->` directives in svelte templates.

https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-svelte

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat unsatisfying solution by adding `/* eslint-disable */` to the bottom of the script tag giving us:

```
<script lang="ts">
  const unsubscribe = promiseWritable.subscribe((value) => {
    promise = value;
  });

  onDestroy(unsubscribe);
  /* eslint-disable */
</script>

{#if !!promise} <---- No ESLint error anymore
  {#await promise then promiseResult}
    <Info {promiseResult} />
  {/await}
{/if}
```

This will disable all linting in the HTML template.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `settings.svelte3/named-blocks` to `true` in your eslint config. [Docs on svelte3/named-blocks](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3#svelte3named-blocks). Then modify the targetted svelte files in `overrides`, and add template into `ignorePatterns`.

Such way requires no `...eslint-disable...` in source files.

```js
    # .eslintrc.cjs
    ...    
    ignorePatterns: [
        "**/*.svelte/*_template.ts",
    ],
    overrides: [{ files: ["**/*.svelte/*.ts"], processor: "svelte3/svelte3" }],
    settings: {
        "svelte3/typescript": () => require("typescript"),
        "svelte3/named-blocks": true,
    },
    ...
```

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3/issues/22)

Comment: I believe that solves the underlining issue (which is awesome!) but this post is more concerned with how we would generally disable ESLint rules in the template

Comment: current [svelte github issue on eslint](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3/issues/134) has been open since september 2021

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm not using typescript - what ignore pattern do I use to ignore the template in my `src/Linear.svelte` file? I've tried different variations of `"**/*.svelte/*_template.js"`, `"*.svelte/*_template.js"`, `"src/Linear_template.svelte"`, etc.